# Android FFMPEG: Could not execute the ffmpeg from Java code

Tags: android, video, ffmpeg

I am working on an Android app where I want to create a video from a
list of static images. After doing some search on internet, it made me
realized that using "FFMPEG" is the way to go in getting this thing
done. So I got hold of this site:
https://github.com/guardianproject/android-ffmpeg-java from where I
downloaded the C library and the Java wrapper. I was able to compile the
C library - of course not the way the instruction was laid out - but
still I was able to get "ffmpeg" executable under
/external/android-ffmpeg/ffmpeg directory. I copied that executable in
my current directory and then copied it to a directory under Android
where my app can access it. Then I called the provided Java wrapper but
I am seeing some errors in the log file like follows:

```
08-13 11:55:37.848: D/FFMPEG(29598): /data/data/com.sample/app_bin/ffmpeg -y -loop 1 -i /storage/emulated/0/usersnapshot/ffmpeg/image%03d.jpg -r 25 -t 2 -qscale 5 /storage/emulated/0/video/snapshot-video.mp4 
08-13 11:55:37.898: I/ShellCallback : shellOut()(29598): /data/data/com.sample/app_bin/ffmpeg[1]: syntax error: '(' unexpected
08-13 11:55:37.938: I/ShellCallback : processComplete()(29598): 1
```

And following is the code snippet (where targetDirectoryForFFMPEG = directory where the images are stored):

```
FfmpegController ffmpegController = new FfmpegController(this, targetDirectoryForFFMPEG);
String out = videoOutPutFile.getPath();
        MediaDesc mediaIn = new MediaDesc();
        mediaIn.path = targetDirectoryForFFMPEG+"/image%03d.jpg";
        mediaIn.videoFps =  "25";   
        ffmpegController.convertImageToMP4(mediaIn, 2, out,new ShellCallback() {

            @Override
            public void shellOut(String shellLine) {
                Log.i("ShellCallback : shellOut()", shellLine);
            }

            @Override
            public void processComplete(int exitValue) {
                Log.i("ShellCallback : processComplete()", exitValue+"");
            }
        });
```

Has anybody implemented this before? If yes, can you point me to what am I doing incorrect? I will provide more information if needed.

Comment: Check permissions for the `ffmpeg` executable.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have root on the device?

Mount '/data' and then enter your same 'ffmpeg' command in the shell and see whether the error is the same.

Try using the shell to test out different command expressions.

Try 'ffmpeg' alone and with just one input file. See whether those commands produce expected output.

My wild guess would be that there is an issue with calling 'ffmpeg.main()'  that relates to the details of your build.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I will definitely try what you said but is it possible to have the ffmpeg exec without compiling the C/C++ code? Why I asked is because I don't know C/C++ and I want to be sure I am not doing anything incorrect.

Comment: ffmpeg unlikely to work on device unless you cross-compile yourself with correct ffmpeg.config() for your specific hardware...

Answer (score 0):

Your ffmpeg might not be compiled properly for the arm.  I was getting the same error when not using a correctly compiled ffmpeg.